# Python Code to create Google Project

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to create a new Google Developer/Cloud project(for an existing Google Account) automatically using a python script ?

If its possible, Can someone please redirect me to some helpful links/references ?

Thanks,

Comment: Any Suggestions, please ?

Comment: Here's my similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666906/gae-python-rest-to-cloud-resource-manager-permission-denied

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible?: Yes, using [App Engine's Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api) or the [Cloud Resource Manager APIs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/apis) with although this functionality is currently in beta as of the time of writing this (08-24-2016). You can access them directly or through a client library.

---

Directly Via REST API:

1. **App Engine Admin API v1beta5**:

   `create   POST /v1beta5/apps`

   > Creates an App Engine application for a Google Cloud Platform project.
   >   This requires a project that excludes an App Engine application...

   More: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1beta5/apps/create
2. **Cloud Resource Manager API v1beta1**:

   `POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/`

   > Creates a Project resource.

   and example request:

   ```
   {
    "name": "project name",
    "projectId": "project-id-1",
    "labels": {
     "environment": "dev"
    },
   }
   ```

   More here: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/create

---

Via a python client library:

1. There's **the [Google Python Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client)**

   ```
   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
   ```

   Then you'll have to build an authenticated service to the api.
   Every other thing you'll need for the request can be found in [this doc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudresourcemanager/v1beta1/python/latest/cloudresourcemanager_v1beta1.projects.html#create)
2. **[gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python#google-cloud-resource-manager)**:

   **Ideally** though, and my personal favorite, you'll want to use this client library to build such a script

   ```
   pip install --upgrade gcloud
   ```

   then you'll create the new project with:

   ```
   from gcloud import resource_manager
   client = resource_manager.Client()

   # re-doing above REST example
   project = client.new_project('project-id-1', name='project name',
                                labels={'environment': 'dev'})
   project.create()
   ```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed reply. I tried the python client library code in a quick manner. It gave the following error: 403 The caller does not have permission (POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects)

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to first authenticate with the google cloud sdk tool(also named gcloud but not to be confused with this client lib), with `gcloud auth login` https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/

Comment: I'm updating the answer with that info. Here's some more info too: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/resource-manager-api.html#authentication

Comment: gcloud auth login is working for my for google service account. I have the Editor Permission access to my service account.

Comment: Should the 'Project Owner' Permission be given to the service account for this task ?

Comment: you should use `gcloud auth login` to auth your user account so that you can create projects under your user. No service account can be used for this I believe

Comment: Getting same error with service account & user account both. Service Account has editor permissions & user account has admin/owner permissions.