# GAE (Python) Cloud Resource Manager - Permission denied

Tags: python, rest, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a project using the appengine `urlfetch` but I get a 403 "The caller does not have permission" error. I'm running this code in production, which should be given permission automatically.

Here's the code:

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import json

project_data = {
    'projectId': 'test-project-84873',
    'name': 'TEST PROJECT'
}

auth_token, _ = app_identity.get_access_token('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform')
response = urlfetch.fetch(
    'https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects',
    payload = json.dumps(project_data),
    method = urlfetch.POST,
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(auth_token),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
)
```

My API has been enabled, and I was able to successfully create a project using the APIs Explorer at the bottom of this page https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create

If I run the same code but with GET instead of POST, it successfully returns the current project information.

Thanks

### EDIT

Strangely, this code works perfectly on my local development server, just not in production... ???

### EDIT 2

I tried to use the Python Client Library which I found near the bottom of this page: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

The code:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

project_data = {
    'projectId': 'project-test-12345',
    'name': 'YAY NEW PROJECT'
}
projects = service.projects().create(body=project_data).execute()
```

I get the same result. It works locally, but not in production :(